# Finding the center and radius of a circle given a general degree 2 equation

Tags: algebra-precalculus, circles

I am trying to find the center and radius of the circle with equation $x^2 + y^2 -6x + 10y + 9 = 0$

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Hint:
Rearrange the equation as follows: $$ x^2-6x + y^2 +10y =-9$$ and [complete the square](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Completing_the_square) in $x$ and $y$
.  You should get something of the form $$(x-a)^2+(y-b)^2 = c^2$$ 
from which you can get the center and the radius.

All the best.

Comment: I forgot what that is.

Comment: @Jordan: I've inserted a link to help you with a review on how to complete squares. If additional help is needed, please ask.

Comment: I have zero idea what to do and the wikipedia link is just full of terms I don't know the meaning of, notation I don't understand and just all sorts of confusion.

Comment: @Jordan: If completing squares seems to be a problem, then I suggest you look at Americo's solution.

Answer (score 3):

You know the equation of a circle has the form
$$
r^2=(x-a)^2+(y-b)^2.
$$
If you have the equation in this form, you can read off the center and radius.

But you don't have that. You need to do a bit of work to get what you have into the form you want.

The tool to use here is:

**Completing the Square**

To *complete the square* for the expression $ax^2+bx+c$ means to find constants $h$ and $k$ such that   $$
     ax^2+bx+c=a(x-h)^2+k.
    $$  To do this, factor out $a$ and add and subtract $b^2\over4a^2$ in the other factor.

For your equation
 $$\color{maroon}{x^2} +\color{darkgreen}{ y^2} \color{maroon}{-6x }\color{darkgreen}{+ 10y }\color{maroon}{+ 9}=0$$
you want to complete the square on the $\color{maroon}x$ and on the $\color{darkgreen}y$ terms on the left hand side.

For the $y$ terms:

$$
\eqalign{ y^2+10y  &= y^2+10y +{100\over4}-{100\over4} \cr 
                   &=  y^2+10y +25-25\cr
                   &= (y+5)^2-25 
}
$$

The other part of your equation is easier to work out (note its easy when you include the 9 with it):
$$
x^2-6x+9=(x-3)^2
$$

So

$$\eqalign{
& \color{maroon}{x^2} +\color{darkgreen}{ y^2} \color{maroon}{-6x }\color{darkgreen}{+ 10y }\color{maroon}{+ 9}\cr& \iff
\color{maroon}{(x-3)^2}+ \color{darkgreen}{ (y+5)^2-25} =0\cr &\iff (x-3)^2+  (y+5)^2=25.
}
$$

So the center and radius are...

Comment: I don't understand $b^2\over4a^2$ where that comes from and why.

Comment: @Jordan $ax^2+bx =a ( x^2+{b\over a} x +D-D)$. If you want $x^2+{b\over a}x+D$ to be a perfect square, then (as it turns out) $D$ has to be $-b^2\over 4a^2$. Check by multiplying out $(x+{-b\over 2a})^2$.

Comment: This is honestly something I will never be able to memorize.

Answer (score 3):

A mechanical way is to start with the usual equation of a circle centered at the point $(a,b)$ and radius $r$ 
$$
(x-a)^{2}+(y-b)^{2}=r^{2},\tag{1}
$$
write it in the form
$$
(x-a)^{2}+(y-b)^{2}-r^{2}=0,
$$

and expand the LHS
$$
\begin{eqnarray*}
(x-a)^{2}+(y-b)^{2}-r^{2} &=&\left( x^{2}-2ax+a^{2}\right) +\left(
y^{2}-2by+b^{2}\right) -r^{2} \\
&=&x^{2}+y^{2}-2ax-2by+a^{2}+b^{2}-r^{2},
\end{eqnarray*}
$$
so that we get the equivalent equation 
$$
x^{2}+y^{2}-2ax-2by+a^{2}+b^{2}-r^{2}=0.\tag{2}
$$

Equating the coefficients of $(2)$ to the ones of the given equation
$$
x^{2}+y^{2}-6x+10y+9=0\tag{3}
$$
results in the system of equations 
$$
\begin{eqnarray*}
-2a &=&-6 \\
-2b &=&10 \\
a^{2}+b^{2}-r^{2} &=&9,
\end{eqnarray*}
$$
which is equivalent to
$$
\begin{eqnarray*}
a &=&3 \\
b &=&-5 \\
9+25-r^{2} &=&9.
\end{eqnarray*}
$$
So the center is the point $(a,b)=(3,-5)$ and the radius is $r=5$, because it cannot be negative (the other solution of $9+25-r^{2} =9$ is $-5$).

Comment: This is a really strange solution to the problem that I doubt I would have ever seen. How did you know to do that? Did you just recognize the equation as the form of two squares involving negatives?

Comment: @Jordan I knew that the equation can be written in the form $(1)$. I just rewrote it in the form $(2)$ to compare it directely with your equation $(3)$.

Comment: Is this how I should be looking at things? I never see equations like that.

Comment: @Jordan Have you never seen an equation of a circle of the form $(1)$?

Comment: It has been a while but yes I have, it is just that I would not be able to translate that to (2).

Comment: But can you follow the details of the calculation from $(1)$ to $(2)$?

Comment: Yes I see that, it just isn't something I would see or be able to recognize on my own.

Comment: @Jordan OK. In my opinion some more practice in algebraic manipulations would be helpful.

Comment: I still have about 7 days to study before I take calculus again so I will try and catch up on that. Really I need to review everything again. I am not sure if it is worth my time and money to take College algebra or whatever for a third time though.

Comment: @Jordan Maybe the folks here at stackexchange can help you with that too - a general plan of study or review to get comfortable with creative problem-solving ideas sounds like a great question to ask/search the archives for.